# Migrate PostgreSQL database to MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, migration, heroku

Say that I want to migrate a PostgreSQL database on Heroku to MySQL on EC2 and I need to preserve the ID values in all the tables, what's the best way to accomplish that without using paid software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite simple.

I would have mySQL instance locally, heroku db:pull to get it from Heroku Postgres to your local development mySQL instance, back it up and then restore the backup to your EC2 MySQL instance

Comment: I'm guessing heroku db:pull preserve the ID values even if they are pulled into a different type of database? If so, then this is a winner.

Comment: yep, it uses TAPS behind the scene, works very well - just watch out sometimes if you've done some DB specific sql that it may break going over to another DB platform.